# Form authentication in jsp page not redirecting

Tags: jsp

The following code authenticates whether an employee has already applied for a post or not. If already applied it redirects to "PRINT" page else it will direct to "ENTRY PAGE". There is one more aspect to this application. That is..the employee can also apply for another employee who is lower than his cadre. this is checked by "LOGIN_AS" variable. The problem i am facing is.. if i place the condition of "LOGIN_AS" in the if-else condition.. it is allowing the employee to fill in for himself too even though he/she has already filled in the same. If i remove it,it is redirecting to the print page but not allowing the employee to apply for lower cadre employee.

"LOGIN_AS" is taken from entry page

```
<%
String appln= request.getParameter("appln");
int empid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("empsrno"));
String login_as = request.getParameter("login_as");
session.putValue("Login_as",login_as);

java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ();
String sql = "SELECT E.SRNO,RTRIM(P.EMAIL_ID),E.NAME,TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),DECODE(E.SRNO,I.SRNO,1,0),"+
             "(to_date('01-DEC-2012','dd/mm/yyyy')-trunc(sysdate)) ,"+
             "DECODE(I.SRNO,'',0,I.SRNO),E.CADRE,I.ITSG_TYP "+
             "FROM EMPFILE E,PFORM_EXCHANGE_USERS P,ONLINE_PFORM_ADMIN A,APPLN I "+
             "WHERE E.SRNO = P.EMPLOYEE_ID AND E.SRNO = A.EMPLOYEE_ID(+) AND E.SRNO=I.SRNO(+)  "+
             "AND E.SRNO=" + request.getParameter("empsrno") +" AND I.APPLN_TYP(+)='APPLN3N12' ";


ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
int x = 0;
int lastDt;
int itsg_eid = 0;
String applnTyp = "X";

 if (rset.next()) 
 {
   if ( request.getParameter("empemail").trim().toLowerCase().concat("@licindia.com").equals(rset.getString(2).toLowerCase()))
       {
        session.putValue("USER",request.getParameter("empsrno"));
        session.putValue("LOGIN","true");
        session.putValue("ENAME",rset.getString(3));
        session.putValue("EMAIL",rset.getString(2));
        session.putValue("SYSDT",rset.getString(4));
        session.putValue("APPLNTYP",appln);
        x = rset.getInt(5);
        lastDt = rset.getInt(6);
        appln_eid = rset.getInt(7);        
        applnTyp = rset.getString(9);
         rset.close();
         stmt.close();
         conn.close();
         if (lastDt == 0)
         {
         %>

         <jsp:forward page="appln_login.jsp"><jsp:param name="message" value="LAST DATE (16/11/2012) FOR SUBMISSION OF APPLICATION IS OVER !!!"/></jsp:forward>

         <%
         }

            if (empid == appln_eid && (applnTyp.equals(itsg)) && login_as=="S")
            {
           session.putValue("PUSER",request.getParameter("empsrno"));   
            %>
           <jsp:forward page="appln_print.jsp"></jsp:forward>
           <% } else {
           %> 
            <jsp:forward page="appln_entry.jsp"></jsp:forward>
            <% }



%>
```

Can any one direct me in correcting the above code....

Answer (score 0):

hey got corrected by a friend of mine

replace if (empid == appln_eid && (applnTyp.equals(appln) && login_as == "S")

by

if (empid == appln_eid && (applnTyp.equals(appln)) && login_as.equals("S"))